# Force style of push notification?

Tags: xcode

I was wondering - is there a way to **force how a push notification will appear** to the iPhone user? There are *3 options* in settings for the user to choose - **none**, some kind of top **banner** that dissappears after a short time and an **alert** with buttons.

The problem is, while developing an application for iPhone, I found out that using the ***didReceiveRemoteNotification*** function did not return any results if I didn't click on that top banner. This doesn't seem to be firing up even when the application is taken to the foreground.

I need those data provided by this function to act upon in my application.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Questions about programming, development, and listing your apps on the App Store are off topic for Ask Different.Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, there is no way for you to do this. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5056935/276656) and the comments below. Probably you should implement another method to poll for events while app is running.

ps. A more appropriate place to ask this question would be [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).